# How to deploy Meteor and Phusion Docker to Digital Ocean with Docker?

Tags: meteor, docker, digital-ocean

What is a workflow for deploying to Digital Ocean with Phusion Docker and Node/Meteor support?

I tried :

```
FROM phusion/passenger-nodejs:0.9.10

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# ssh
ADD private/keys/akey.pub /tmp/your_key
RUN cat /tmp/your_key >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f /tmp/your_key

## Download shit
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qq -y python-software-properties software-properties-common curl git build-essential
RUN npm install fibers@1.0.1
# install meteor
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Enable nginx
# RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down


#setup app
RUN mkdir /home/app/someapp
ADD . /home/app/someapp
WORKDIR /home/app/someapp
EXPOSE 4000
CMD passenger start -p 4000
```

But nothing is working and then I'm not sure how to really manage update/deploy/running?

E.g, how would you also handle updating the app without rebuilding the docker image?

Comment: your question is too broad and you are not describing a precise issue you have but ask the community to make it work. Start by following one of the numerous tutorials for docker to get familiar with it. Then read more carefully the docker passenger readme file, you need at least the instruction `RUN /build/nodejs.sh` in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggested workflow:

1. Create an account on [Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/accounts/), you can get 1 private repository for free. If you want a complete private repository hosted on your own server, you can run an entire [docker registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) and use it to host your images.
2. Create your image on your development machine (locally or on a server), then push the image to the repository using `docker push`
3. Update the image when needed and commit your changes with `docker commit` then push the updated image to your repository (you should properly version and tag all your images)
4. You can start a digital ocean droplet with docker pre-installed (from applications tab) and simply pull your image and run your container. Whenever you update and push your image from your development machine, simple pull it again from the droplet.

For large and complex infrastructure, I would recommend looking into Ansible to configure your [docker containers](http://docs.ansible.com/docker_module.html) and manage [digital ocean droplet](http://docs.ansible.com/digital_ocean_module.html) as well.

Be aware that your data will be lost if you stop the container, so consider defining a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume) in your container that is mapped to a shared folder on your host machine

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you test your Dockerfile in a local VirtualBox VM. I wrote a tutorial about deploying node.js app with Docker. I build several images (layers) instead of just 1. When you update your app, you just need to rebuild the top layer. Hope it helps. http://vinceyuan.blogspot.com/2015/05/deploying-web-app-redis-postgres-and.html